# Which numpy function does as same work as my circumstance?

Tags: python, numpy

First, my code is :

```
A = np.array_with_values((1600,1200,4))
B = np.array_with_other_values((1600,1200,4))
argb = np.argmax(B,axis=-1)
newA = np.zeros((1600,1200))
for v in range(A.shape[0]):
    for u in range(A.shape[1]):
        newA[v,u] = A[v,u,argb[v,u]]
```

Here my goal is to find numpy function that can replace the for loops since I know that for loop is so slow.

Anybody know the answer and thank you very much.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example, a description of the logic, and the expected output

Comment: Which version of `numpy` are you using? I can't find information for `np.array_with_values` or `np.array_with_other_values`.

Comment: Looks like [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html).